# Get last saturday date of a particular month and year

Tags: linux, date, awk, cut

I get a source file in the format of `SOURCE_FILE_042014.CSV` which contains data for the month of April in 2014. . From this I need to get the last saturday of that month and load that data against this date in our system. For example - the date for which the data of the file `SOURCE_FILE_042014.CSV` should be `04262014`. After I do a substring using cut command and with help from **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10436146/the-last-saturday-of-a-given-month-year)**, I get only the date as `26`. How to display the complete week date?

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: @LevLevitsky I am expecting the week_date output as `04262014`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract the year and month from the filename to be able to ask for the last Saturday. So, just get the day back and compose it back with the year and month you already extracted:

```
#! /bin/bash
filename=SOURCE_FILE_042014.CSV
date=${filename##*_}
date=${date%.CSV}

month=${date:0:2}
year=${date:2}

day=$(cal $month $year | awk 'NF>6{a=$7} END{print a}')

echo $month$day$year
```